# why transition methods like `beforeLeave` not working in nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to code to achieve such an effect： [Advanced fade transition (with height)](https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/vue-router-page-transitions/#advanced-fade-transition-with-height)

I follow the [nuxt document](https://zh.nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/components-glossary/pages-transition/#object) add the `transition` in `layouts/default.vue`

```js
<template>
    <main>
        ...
        <nuxt/>
        ...
    </main>
</template>
<script>
export default{
    data(){
        return {
             prevHeight: 0
        }
    },
    transition: {
        beforeLeave(element) {
            console.log(element)
            this.prevHeight = getComputedStyle(element).height;
        },
        enter(element) {
            console.log(element)
            const { height } = getComputedStyle(element);

            element.style.height = this.prevHeight;

            setTimeout(() => {
                element.style.height = height;
            });
        },
        afterEnter(element) {
            console.log(element)
            element.style.height = 'auto';
        }
    }
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.page-enter-active,
.page-leave-active {
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-property: height, opacity;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.page-enter,
.page-leave-active {
  opacity: 0
}
</style>
```

but none of `console.log(element)` work.

I already googled for it but nothing helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fixed it. The `transition` should add in nuxt page-component instead of layout-component